# Unexpected character in Kafka Connect REST request

Tags: curl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am successfully running kafka connect in standalone mode but when it comes to distributed mode then I am getting error while calling rest api to publish connnector.

Here is POST call
    `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" --data  <path to json>/mysql_dist.json  http://xxxxxxxxxx:8083/connectors/`

When I execute above call then I get error.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /connectors/. Reason:
<pre>    Request failed.</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

here is MySQL-sourceconnecter json file

```
{
  "name": "mysql-connector",  
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", 
    "database.hostname": "localhost", 
    "database.port": "3306", 
    "database.user": "root", 
    "database.password": "admin", 
    "database.server.id": "42", 
    "database.server.name": "demo", 
    "database.whitelist": "mydbb", 
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "xxxxxxxxxx:6667", 
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "mydbb.student", 
    "include.schema.changes": "true",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "database.history.store.only.monitored.tables.ddl": "false",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "true",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.deletes": "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show the json file you're posting

Comment: Question updated with json file

Comment: "config" is missing a colon

Comment: I tested with that too but same error

Comment: Why are you using `--data path/mysql_dist.json`? If you are trying to post a file, you need to give an `@` before the file path, otherwise, it just posts that string

Comment: Perfect , You are helpful as always